# Azure Website File Upload File Not found exception

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have an App Service of type Web App as a paid plan in Azure and am attempting to allow a form on the asp.net core site to upload files into a directory off of the web root. Not sure if it is a factor but there is continuous integration configured with the git repository on the master branch.

The code I wrote works locally but throws this error when executed on Azure.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\fullsteam-uploads\20190627_1239023614_015157371.png'.
>   File name: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot\fullsteam-uploads\20190627_1239023614_015157371.png'
>      at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
>      at pcs_fullsteamapi.Services.FilesService.SaveLeadsFiles(LeadsModel model) in D:\a\1\s\pcs-fullsteamapi\Services\FilesService.cs:line 31

The relevant portion of the code

```
model.FileNames = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
foreach (var file in model.Files)
{
    var fileName = GetFileName(model.PipelinePersonId.ToString(), file);
    await file.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(destinationPath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create));
    model.FileNames.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(file.FileName, fileName));
}
```

The path matches the server exactly with fullsteam-uploads being an empty directory. Line 31 is the await file.Copy.

Comment: I am not putting this as the answer, because I don't truly understand why this is now working.  I moved the destination folder to just D:\home\site\uploads and it began working.  I am going to set up a virtual directory to allow access to it.

Comment: Did you immediately get the error or only when a build was deployed? It is possible your build was deleting anything in the wwwroot folder not included in the build.

Comment: The error came immediately Samara.  My final solution was to use an Azure Storage account instead.  Was a very easy API to integrate with and worked great.